# How can i arrange columns as per given condition?

Tags: r

My data set is :

```
S1   S2   S3    S4 
1    4    7     20
2    6    8     21
3    9    10    30
```

and i convert data as per condition that
sort as per maximum difference value between each column value

data after the condition should be like this

```
S4    S2    S3    S1 
20    4     7     1
21    6     8     2
30    9     1     3
```

explanation:
the difference between max and min value

```
for S4 is 30 - 20 =10

for S2 is 9-4 = 5

for S3 is 10-7 = 3

for S1 is 3-1 =2
```

and the columns are sorted as per the difference value of max and min.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an idea via base R,

```
df[order(sapply(df, function(i) max(i)-min(i)), decreasing = TRUE)]
```

which gives,

> ```
>   S4 S2 S3 S1
> 1 20  4  7  1
> 2 21  6  8  2
> 3 30  9 10  3
> ```

If you want to change the column names to reflect the order you can use `setNames`, i.e.

```
setNames(df[order(sapply(df, function(i) max(i)-min(i)), decreasing = TRUE)], 
         paste0('column', seq_along(df)))
```

which gives,

> ```
>    column1 column2 column3 column4
> 1      20       4       7       1
> 2      21       6       8       2
> 3      30       9      10       3
> ```

Comment: and how can i give name to the columns same as per condition?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: like if i want to give name to second highest column from "S2" to "column2" and same for all columns i.e column1 etc..

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: and if i want names as column1, value_column2, 3_data_column, column_4_id then how can i do it?

Comment: Thanks for your Help :D

Comment: No problem. Please accept one of the answers (check tickmark next to it) so we can consider this question closed

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% 
   summarise_all(funs(max(.)-min(.))) %>%
   unlist %>% 
   order(., decreasing = TRUE) %>% 
   select(df1, .)
#  S4 S2 S3 S1
#1 20  4  7  1
#2 21  6  8  2
#3 30  9 10  3
```

Comment: and if i want names as column1, value_column2, 3_data_column, column_4_id then how can i do it?

Comment: I get `Error in select(df, .) : unused argument (.)`

Comment: @RahulSemwal  You can use `rename_at`

Comment: @Sotos I used `dplyr_0.7.2`

Comment: Same here...`[1] ‘0.7.2’`

Comment: @Sotos Not sure what would be the problem.  I got it installed recently

Comment: hmm... Let me update the rest of the packages...Maybe something with dependencies...

Comment: data is arranged but column name is still not there as per condition.

Comment: @RahulSemwal  IN your post `data after the condition should be like this` it shows with the same column names

Comment: No, i also want to change the column name as "column1", "value_column2", "3_data_column", "column_4_id".

Comment: ahh...ok updated the rest of the packages and works great. Nice 1 :)

Comment: Thanks i did it using setNames(df[order(sapply(df, function(i) max(i)-min(i)), decreasing = TRUE)],  c("c1","c2","c3","c4"))

Comment: Thank you for your Help, Nice :D

Answer (score 0):

```
 df1[,order(sapply(df1,function(x)diff(range(x))),decreasing = T)]
   S4 S2 S3 S1
 1 20  4  7  1
 2 21  6  8  2
 3 30  9 10  3
```